# What is the equivalent of root in Windows 8.1, and how can I open a shell in that context?

Tags: windows-8.1, shell, permissions, administrator, root

I've heard the equivalent of root is the "SYSTEM" account. But I used a tool called "RunAsSystem" to open a shell as SYSTEM, and I'm still getting "access denied" errors even though I know the files in question aren't in use. How can I get a shell from which I can perform any action on any file regardless of whatever permissions are set?

**EDIT:** This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/139841/access-denied-even-though-im-an-administrator). That one is asking why a standard administrator account doesn't have certain permissions; I'm asking if there's an account that has full permissions for everything.

**EDIT2:** It's not a duplicate of [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/614165/command-prompt-as-system-user-win-7) either. That question is asking how to get a command prompt as the SYSTEM user. In my question I've clearly stated that I was able to do so, so I'm certainly not asking how to do that.

Also, I haven't chosen an accepted answer yet because I haven't decided yet--I didn't forget, if you were wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you need is to enable Backup and Restore privileges, granted by default to the Administrators group. One way to do that is to use [this PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Adjusting-Token-Privileges-9b6724fc):

```powershell
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Process
Import-Module .\Set-LHSTokenPrivilege.ps1
Set-LHSTokenPrivilege SeBackupPrivilege
Set-LHSTokenPrivilege SeRestorePrivilege
```

With Backup and Restore privileges you will have full access to any file or folder regardless of their own access control list.

Comment: Nice, never thought of using SeBackupPrivilege\SeRestorePrivilege from this angle. Thanks!

Comment: Good idea, and that looks like a useful script. But I'm still getting some "access denied" errors. I'm testing it by trying to create a file in `C:\program files\windowsapps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_6.3.9600.20278_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe`, as well as trying to append (using `>>`) to `app.xaml` within that folder. Both have failed using this method.

Comment: Looks like Windows protect files inside WindowsApps somehow besides normal access control lists. Even if I explicitly grant full access to everyone, files still unavailable to edit. `icacls` shows extra entity in ACL for `S-1-19-512-4096` SID, that is not shown in GUI, maybe it related somehow.

Comment: @PetSerAl I have a similar problem here http://superuser.com/questions/1039116/cannot-write-on-windowsapps-directories-and-restore-files

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Even being `SYSTEM` you can't access files or other objects if you don't have permissions to do so. But being `root` you can change permissions and only then access files\objects.

The typical case for this is the Windows system files on modern Windows versions (Vista and higher): most of them belong to the [TrustedInstaller](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/trustedinstaller-exe-windows-7) user, and no one other can't delete\modify them. You need first to [become owner](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html) and then [change permissions](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2815-permissions-allow-deny-access-users-groups-windows-8-a.html) to allow you to access them.