# undocumented SID structure on windows 10 [S-1-19-512-4096]

Tags: windows, windows-10, security

regarding this question: [Cannot write on WindowsApps directories and restore files](https://superuser.com/questions/1039116/cannot-write-on-windowsapps-directories-and-restore-files)

After hitting to wall trying to restore some files inside this directory `c:\Program Files\WindowsApps\` on **windows 10** I hit over this undocumented SID

**S-1-19-512-4096**

Files using icacls give this results

**S-1-19-512-4096:(I)(RX,D,WDAC,WO,WA)**

and no one have permissions to restore them, change them, rename them delete them.

I have Google it and found only two results, I bealive this question will be the third one.

Is there any information's about that and how to disabled or change it or take over it, because is not let me restore files after have been deleted.

Comment: I came across this too. What's weird is that when I get the permissions using icacls, this SID is there, but when I get the permissions using Win32's GetFileSecurity or GetSecurityInfo, this SID isn't there. Using PowerShell's Get-Acl, it's not there either. What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this is an old question, but I came across this same SID dealing with my own machine's problems. According to "Windows Internals Seventh Edition", Yosifovich *et. al.*, this SID corresponds to the WinTCB signer (i.e. the Windows trusted computing base).

It may be possible to interact with these files while running as `NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

Comment: its an old question, but is still active - the main issue here is that the computer can take the control from you and you can not do anything...

Comment: @Aristos The whole point of the WinTCB is that code is signed and a non-human role account handles administration. If you really need to interact with a directory owned by one of the system SIDs, use a tool that lets you run a program as `NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM` i.e. S-1-5-18.